# PayPal - 10001 internal error: timeout processing request Express Checkout

Tags: vb.net, paypal, express-checkout

I have a problem with the Express Checkout. I tried all the solution provided in the web but I cannot make it work!
I'm using VB 2012 for Web and ASP.NET. I built a cart in the web site and try to integrate PayPal Express Checkout (for now using the test account in Sandbox).
When I click on the PayPal button it shows me the error:

10001 Internal Error: Timeout processing request

Debugging the application I found that the problem is when he try to make the call:

```
Try
    Using myWriter As New StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream())
          myWriter.Write(strPost)
    End Using
Catch e As Exception
End Try
```

Where strPost is the following:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a63223%2fCheckout%2fCheckoutReview.aspx&CANCELURL=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a63223%2fCheckout%2fCheckoutCancel.aspx&BRANDNAME=PayPal+Sample+Application&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=36&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=36&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0+_NAME=Modena&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=36&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY=1&USER=minni_1356740302_biz_api1.gmail.com&PWD=1356740320&SIGNATURE=AlYEmGf5ECuFHhwJgGlXJ.tMCTY0AFMcAx3nUjv6Ssg4RlD7YYwyoOJb&VERSION=88.0&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard
```

What could be wrong?

I really need help..​Any and all help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This error could simply mean there's an issue with the PayPal sandbox servers, or it could mean you have a problem with your request.  I was able to successfully hit the sandbox with SetExpressCheckout just now, though, so I'm guessing it must have something to do with your request.

One thing I see right away is that you won't be able to use localhost in your ReturnURL and CancelURL because at the time that gets used it will be running from PayPal's server.  As such, "localhost" will be their server, not yours, and the redirect won't work.  You'll need to use your own public IP address or setup a domain of some sort to point to your test server.  That could be what their server isn't liking.

Another thing I notice is that you're just using the value 36 for your amounts.  PayPal documentation specifies you need to use two decimal places on amount values, so you need to make sure and pass 36.00 instead.

The next thing I notice, which is probably what's causing your problem, is that one of your parameter names is invalid:  [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0+_NAME]

You need to get that + out of there.  I bet that'll fix your issue, but I'd still get those other things fixed up, too.

Comment: Basically almost any issue with your request or on their side will result in `10001 Internal Error: Timeout processing request`. What an outstanding API design!